# How to Place 2 TikZ Plots Side by Side

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm working on something that involves placing plot sketches side by side. The trouble is, even though I begin the next picture on the same line as the previous one ends, it doesn't look nice:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw [->] (0,0) -- (0,2) node [left,pos=1] {$\Delta x$} node [above right] at (0.5,2) {Guy};
\draw [->] (0,0) -- (2.1,0) node [below, pos=0.9] {$\Delta t$};
\draw (0,-1) -- (1,0) -- (2,1);

\end{tikzpicture} \begin{tikzpicture}

\draw [->] (0,0) -- (0,2) node [left,pos=1] {$\Delta x$} node [above right] at (0.5,2) {Car};
\draw [->] (0,0) -- (2.1,0) node [below, pos=0.9] {$\Delta t$};
\draw [domain=0:0.89] plot (\x, {2.5*\x*\x});

\end{tikzpicture}
```

What is wrong, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Add `[baseline]` to each of your `\begin{tikzpicture}`'s (*i.e.*, they should be `\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]` instead of `\begin{tikzpicture}`), and this should solve your problem.

Comment: Will do. Thanks for the help; but just curiously, I must ask what does baseline do exactly? About what axis does it center the graphs?

Answer (score 7):

For the sake of illustration, it will be easiest to make your `tikzpicture`'s appear inlign with some text. Normally, the bottom of a `tikzpicture` is put on the baseline of the surrounding text. So, if we take your code and add `A` and `B` on either side, we get:

[image]

This makes sense. The lowest point in the first `tikzpicture` (*i.e.*, the bottom end of the plotted line) is aligned with the baseline of the text, and the lowest point of the second `tikzpicture` (*i.e.*, the bottom of the label for the x-axis) is also aligned with the baseliene of the surrounding text.

However, you can change this alignment with the TikZ style `baseline`, which allows you to specify what point will be put on the baseline of surrounding text. `baseline` is short for `baseline=0pt`, which puts the x-axis of the `tikzpicture` on the baseline of the surrounding text:

[image]

As you can see, the x-axis is what is aligned to the baseline of the surrounding text. Here's the code for this. (Again, `baseline=0pt` is the same as `baseline`.)

### MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

A \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=0pt]

\draw [->] (0,0) -- (0,2) node [left,pos=1] {$\Delta x$} node [above right] at (0.5,2) {Guy};
\draw [->] (0,0) -- (2.1,0) node [below, pos=0.9] {$\Delta t$};
\draw (0,-1) -- (1,0) -- (2,1);

\end{tikzpicture} \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=0pt]

\draw [->] (0,0) -- (0,2) node [left,pos=1] {$\Delta x$} node [above right] at (0.5,2) {Car};
\draw [->] (0,0) -- (2.1,0) node [below, pos=0.9] {$\Delta t$};
\draw [domain=0:0.89] plot (\x, {2.5*\x*\x});

\end{tikzpicture} B

\end{document}
```

Rather than specifying a particular dimension for `baseline`, you can also specify a coordinate. For complete details, see page 125 of the current [TikZ documentation](http://ctan.mirrors.hoobly.com/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf).